# Significance the run verb

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

This is excerpt from a site:

*The CIA has announced its new deputy director as Gina Haspel, who took part in covert interrogation programs on Al-Qaeda suspects, and even ran a ‘black site’ prison in Thailand that used torture for questionings, the Washington Post reports.*

**What is the significance of the  run  verb ???**

Comment: To 'run' an organisation or facility implies that one is not just a titular head delegating everything to all and sundry and remotely dictating policy at arms' length but that one retains the direct responsibility of day-to-day decisions and hands-on management. The example actually 'ran' the black site, and did not only have executive oversight of it. Whatever happened there is down to them.

Comment: @NigelJ that is...........the man is not head of a prison but some executive position ???

Comment: The person is now Deputy Director of the CIA. _In the past_ they 'ran' (presumably on the actual site in Thailand) the prison. P.S. I assume 'Gina' is a woman.

Comment: @NigelJ Ok......That is.........the woman wasn't a head of prison but occupied some executive position ???

Comment: Please read my last comment again. She _ran_ the place. She was the Boss.

Comment: In the UK we sometimes say that the Prime Minster "runs" the country. That certainly does not mean "retains the direct responsibility of day-to-day decisions and hands-on management". In any particular context, such as the CIA case referred to by the OP, the precise meaning of "run" can only be established by looking at the details.

Comment: The true "significance" of the term in this case is probably that no more specific term such as her exact job title is available, because the details are classified. (All of the news articles I've seen use vague terms like "oversaw", "in charge", and this quote's "ran", which make it clear that she had authority over the facility but aren't quite as descriptive as something like "was warden/chief of operations/head torturer".)

Answer (score 1):

In this sense, *run* means *to operate*, or *to be in charge of*.

Comment: to work in a prison ???

Comment: To operate a prison. To be in charge of a prison.

Comment: Yes, sorry: it meant that Haspel was operating the prison.

Answer (score 0):

Collins English Dictionary via thefreedictionary.com defines "run" as:

> 21. (tr) to be in charge of; manage: to run a company.

Which is the general meaning when run relates to a person and an organisation in this way. But there are a **lot** of definitions for "run"!